# Python weird ImportError: No module named error

Tags: python, module

I've created a python software that should run as a service. It has a module and a script, which goes under /etc/init.d . I used distutils to package the system. Everything installs fine, but when I try to run the script from /etc/init.d, it raises the exception below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/etc/init.d/printserver.py", line 11, in <module>
    from myprintserver import *
  File "/etc/rc.d/init.d/printserver.py", line 12, in <module>
    import myprintserver.printserver 
ImportError: No module named printserver
```

When I try to import the module through command line, it works perfectly.

```
[root@linuxbox Code]# python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 10:05:38) 
[GCC 4.7.0 20120507 (Red Hat 4.7.0-5)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from myprintserver import *
>>> from myprintserver.printserver import *
>>> daemon = PrintServer('/tmp/printer-daemon.pid','/dev/null','/tmp/dlog','/tmp/dlog')
>>>
```

I checked the module under site-packages and everything looks fine. I printed sys.path before the error show up and /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages is included. sys.path printout below:

```
['/etc/rc.d/init.d', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/escpos-1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyusb-1.0.0a3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL-1.1.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

Comment: Look at the path for the `printserver.py` lines in your traceback; something odd about those? The second line is *not* being imported from your site-packages..

Comment: Yes, that much I got. The question is why? What could be causing that? Apparently the file is under site-packages/myprintserver .

Comment: Well, what _is_ `sys.path` (all of it) when printed out from your init.d script?

Comment: I've added the sys.path printout to the post.

Comment: @JulianoBittencourt: No it isn't; `/etc/rc.d/init.d/printserver.py` is being imported when `/etc/init.d/printserver.py` runs `from myprintserver import *`. Something is funny with your python path or there is a simlink in `/etc/init.d`.

Comment: Note the *first* entry in your sys.path: '/etc/rc.d/init.d'

Comment: try running it manually outside your Code directory and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused because the script under /etc/init.d had the same name of the module. Therefore when I tried to include the module, the  script itself was included .

Changing the name of the script solved the issue.

Since the script doesn't have a class named printserver, the error was raised. This wasn't an issue during the development because both module and script where in the same dir, and module was included first.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, you should accept your own answer.